# how to show text below icon in toolbar menu?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-custom-view

Basically we use toolbar menu with icon, sometimes we also use icon/text together. Icon along with Text show horizontally like this image below

[image]

In normal case it happens but I want to show the menu icon/text vertically like the image below

[image]

I have done the xml layout with this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/bg_timeline"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/label_timeline" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_about_large"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/label_about" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_achivement_active"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/label_achievements" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_more"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/label_more" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is how can I implement a toolbar/actionbar when menu item placed like Text below each icon as a whole. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I don't want to use ViewPager instead I am looking for custom view for ToolBar as when user click on more I will show more menu options.

Comment: I did also tried it.. but unable to do it.. you can check https://codeload.github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android/zip/master Android Custom Vertical Dropdown Icons Menu

Answer (score 6):

You can use a toolbar method **inflateMenu** to inflate a custom menu layout. Below is a small snippet:

1. Define your custom menu **your_menu** inside the menu folder:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/your_id"
>         android:title="@string/your_string"
>         android:icon="@drawable/your_menu_icon"
>         app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"
>         app:showAsAction = "always"
>         />
> </menu>
> ```

2. Now define the **your_custom_menu_layout**:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingRight="10dp">
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="30dp"
>         android:layout_height="30dp"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
>         android:paddingRight="5dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/your_menu_icon" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:paddingLeft="0dp"
>         android:text="your_text"
>         android:textColor="@color/white"
>         android:textSize="9dp" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

3. Thirdly, inflate your menu item in your java code using your toolbar:

> your_toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu);

4. Reference and click listeners:

> Menu menu = your_toolbar.getMenu();
>
> View your_menu_view = menu.findItem(R.id.your_id).getActionView();
>           your_menu_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>            @Override
>            public void onClick(View v) {
>             }   });

Comment: Works perfect, in case you can't perform click on menu item :

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_custom, menu);
        final MenuItem itemMyProfile = menu.findItem(R.id.bt_my_profile);
        final Menu finalMenu = menu;
        itemMyProfile.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalMenu.performIdentifierAction(itemMyProfile.getItemId(), 0);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

Comment: So I'm trying to do this a Drawer Menu and does not appear to be working.  Do I have just one Item in the Menu and then put all of the "items" then in the layout?

Comment: https://material.io/components/android/catalog/navigation-view/ 
All that you'll need for a long long time.